# Working with regex for alphanumeric

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying a regex fro Alpha Numeric of length 7 (with positions 1,3,4 as characters and positions 2,5,6,7 as digits).

```
[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.  Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: I think you need `^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$`, see [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/OPLkmz/1)

Comment: `|` joins alternatives (**a** *OR* **b**). Your expression matches a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`) or a digit (`[0-9]`). The rest, starting with the second `|` is redundant. And it doesn't work as you need, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence "character, digit, character, character, digit, digit, digit" is expressed in regex as

```
[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}
```

Comment: Yours will match that sequence, [even if it occurs within a longer string of characters joined to it](https://regex101.com/r/20loKK/3). `HWKBENB3TY819638290`

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in PCRE (with say, PHP):

```
^([a-zA-Z])([0-9])(?1){2}(?2){3}$
```

Breakdown:

- `^` - from the start of the string
- `([a-zA-Z])` - match and capture a single character in the ranges given: a-z, A-Z
- `([0-9])` - match and capture a single character in the ranges given: 0-9
- `(?1){2}` - redo the regex in the first group twice (recursive subpattern)
- `(?2){3}` - redo the regex in the second group 3 times (recursive subpattern)
- `$` - the end of the string

If you want to match this in the middle of a sentence, exchange `^` and `$` for `\b` - which will match a word boundary

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/20loKK/1)

If you're not using PCRE:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$
```

Which does the same thing, but has some copy-paste involved